# How can I use a custom hash function in a HashSet or HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashcode

Since SipHasher is too slow for my use case, I'm trying to implement a custom hash function. I found [an example](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/librustc/util/nodemap.rs) which I used as base to get everything compiling.

My current code looks like this:

```
use std::collections::hash_state::{DefaultState};
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};
use std::default::Default;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher, SipHasher};
use std::marker;

pub struct FnvHasher(u64);

impl Default for FnvHasher {
    fn default() -> FnvHasher { FnvHasher(0xcbf29ce484222325) }
}

impl Hasher for FnvHasher {
    fn write(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]) {
        let FnvHasher(mut hash) = *self;
        for byte in bytes {
            hash = hash ^ (*byte as u64);
            hash = hash * 0x100000001b3;
        }
        *self = FnvHasher(hash);
    }
    fn finish(&self) -> u64 { self.0 }
}

fn main() {
    let mut set:HashSet<i64, DefaultState<FnvHasher>> = HashSet::with_hash_state(DefaultState::<FnvHasher>);
}
```

When I compile I get the following error message:

```
$ rustc -V
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (522d09dfe 2015-02-19) (built 2015-02-19)

$ rustc hash.rs
hash.rs:26:86: 26:111 error: mismatched types:
 expected `std::collections::hash::state::DefaultState<FnvHasher>`,
    found `fn(core::marker::PhantomData<FnvHasher>) -> std::collections::hash::state::DefaultState<FnvHasher> {std::collections::hash::state::DefaultState}`
(expected struct `std::collections::hash::state::DefaultState`,
    found fn item) [E0308]
hash.rs:26         let mut set:HashSet<i64, DefaultState<FnvHasher>> = HashSet::with_hash_state(DefaultState::<FnvHasher>);
                                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

How can I get the above example to compile or use a custom hash function in a HashSet/HashMap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the definition of `DefaultState`:

```
pub struct DefaultState<H>(marker::PhantomData<H>);
```

You are treating it as though it were as it used to be:

```
pub struct DefaultState<H>;
```

This change is recent; generic parameters must now be expressly used.

For this you must now use `Default::default()`, for that field is private, preventing literal expressions from being written. Thus, `DefaultState::<FnvHasher>` becomes `Default::default()`.

And once you’re using `Default::default()` for that, you might as well go the whole hog and replace `HashSet::with_hash_state(Default::default())` with `Default::default()`:

```
let mut set: HashSet<i64, DefaultState<FnvHasher>> = Default::default();
```

Answer (score 7):

[Rust 1.7](http://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/03/02/Rust-1.7.html) stabilized the use of custom hashers. For example, you can use `FnvHasher` from the [fnv](https://crates.io/crates/fnv) crate

```
extern crate fnv;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::BuildHasherDefault;
use fnv::FnvHasher;

type HashMapFnv<K, V> = HashMap<K, V, BuildHasherDefault<FnvHasher>>;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMapFnv::default();
    map.insert(1, "Hello");
    map.insert(2, ", world!");
    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```