# Is there a way to override the equality and hash functions of a type for a particular HashSet or HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashmap, hashset

I have a `User` struct:

```rust
struct User {
    id: i32,
    email: String,
    // ...
}
```

In one part of my code I want to get unique users by database ID but in another piece of code I want to get unique users by email address. I have worked on systems before where users got mapped to external system accounts using LDAP CNs, email, etc. and being able to map a user by a different ID in some situations is very useful.

In .NET you can pass in an [`IEqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer__0__) interface to override equals/hash for a particular `Dictionary`. In C++, the [`unordered_map`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) class has generic parameters for the hash and eq functions. In Java, I've learned to just use `Map`s instead of `Set`s when I want to get unique values keyed off something, but this can be awkward, especially for compound keys.

Truthfully, this is a pretty rare situation and there's always the workaround of using maps instead of sets or creating a wrapper struct with its own `Hash`/`Eq` `impl` block. I am just curious if there's a simpler way to do this in Rust that I am just not aware of yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one or more [newtypes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.49.0/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-for-type-safety-and-abstraction) with the specific definitions of equality and hashing you want:

```rust
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

struct ById(User);

impl Hash for ById {
    fn hash<H>(&self, h: &mut H)
    where
        H: Hasher,
    {
        self.0.id.hash(h)
    }
}

impl PartialEq for ById {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.0.id == other.0.id
    }
}

impl Eq for ById {}
```

```rust
fn example(k: User, v: i32) {
    let mut h = std::collections::HashMap::new();
    h.insert(ById(k), v);
}
```

> Do I need to use `.0` to get at the underlying `User` when I pull `ById`s out of the map?

Yes.

> Is there any magic to implicitly convert to the underlying `User`?

No.

> I might be better off implementing `Deref` or something.

[Is it considered a bad practice to implement Deref for newtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45086595/155423)

See also:

- [How to implement Eq and Hash for my own structs to use them as a HashMap key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31835647/155423)
- [How to use a struct's member as its own key when inserting the struct into a map without duplicating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41035869/155423)
- [How can I use a custom hash function in a HashSet or HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28644070/155423)
- [Are there any HashMap implementations with consistent ordering between program runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45894401/155423)

Comment: Do I need to use `.0` to get at the underlying `User` when I pull `ById`s out of the map? Is there any magic to implicitly convert to the underlying `User`? Although, I could see that being too magical. I might be better off implementing `Deref` or something. Thoughts?

Comment: I've replied inline.